# Constructing model.matrix in R cannot fit in memory (tried all memory-mapping packages)

Tags: r, lm, model.matrix, filehash

I am trying to estimate an `lm()` fitment in R for a large sales dataset. The data itself is not so large that R cannot handle it; about 250MB in memory. The problem is when `lm()` is invoked to include all variables and cross-terms, the construction of the `model.matrix()` throws the error saying that the machine has run out of memory and cannot allocate the vector of size whatever (in this case, about 47GB). Understandable, I don't have that much RAM. The problem is, I have tried the `ff`, `bigmemory`, and `filehash` packages, all of which work fine for working outside of memory with the existing files (I particularly like the database functions of `filehash`). But I cannot, for the life of me, get the `model.matrix` to be created at all. I think the issue is that, despite mapping the output file to the database I created, R tries to set it up in RAM anyway, and can't. Is there a way to avoid this using these packages, or am I doing something wrong?
[Also, using `biglm` and other functions to do things chunk-wise doesn't even allow me to chunk by one at a time. Again, it seems R is trying to make the WHOLE `model.matrix` first, before chunking it]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(filehash)
library(ff)
library(ffbase)
library(bigmemory)
library(biganalytics)
library(dummies)
library(biglm)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)



SID <- readRDS('C:\\JDA\\SID.rds')
SID <- as.data.frame(unclass(SID)) # to get characters as Factors

dbCreate('reg.db')
db <- dbInit('reg.db')
dbInsert(db, 'SID', SID)
rm(SID)
gc()

db$summary1 <-
  db$SID %>%
  group_by(District, Liable, TPN, mktYear, Month) %>%
  summarize(NV.sum = sum(NV))

start.time <- Sys.time()
# Here is where it throws the error:
db$fit <- lm(NV.sum ~ .^2, data = db$summary1)
Sys.time() - start.time
rm(start.time)
gc()

summary(fit)
anova(fit)
```

Comment: Try using a sparse matrix from the `Matrix` package.

Comment: How many variables do you have? How many observations?

Comment: @NealFultz, that did the trick, thank you. The matrix is now occupying memory space. However (and this may be rudimentary), I had planned on finding a way to construct a `model.matrix` first, then just plug that in to an `lm` function. I was throwing errors earlier; is there a way to do that, or to specify the `model.matrix` creation in the `lm` call to make it a sparse one?

@MrFlick, there are about 750,000 observations in the original dataset, about 113,000 in the aggregated one (the one I'm using), and 6 variables, 5 of which are factors, and 2 of which have over 100 levels.

Comment: Generally buying more RAM would help. If you have problems at this stage, they will probably appear also later on with more complicated operations.

Comment: It's the 100 factors by 100 factors interaction term that is blowing things up.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the example from solve-methods in the Matrix package:

```
> ?`solve-methods`
> n1 <- 7; n2 <- 3
> dd <- data.frame(a = gl(n1,n2), b = gl(n2,1,n1*n2))# balanced 2-way
> X <- sparse.model.matrix(~ -1+ a + b, dd)# no intercept --> even sparser
> Y <- rnorm(nrow(X))
> # Forming normal equations manually and solving for beta-hat 
> solve(crossprod(X), crossprod(X, Y))
9 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
            [,1]
 [1,]  1.2384385
 [2,]  1.3313779
 [3,]  0.7497135
 [4,]  0.7840841
 [5,]  0.9586135
 [6,]  0.4667769
 [7,]  1.6648260
 [8,] -1.6669776
 [9,] -1.1142240
```